# Stop the animation play on click in html canvas

Tags: javascript, html

Animated the image move inside the canvas but now can't pause the motion. The image is on moving around the canvas and once click on the eye it should stop or pause. The eye is defined as an HTML image map

I tried using pause() and clearInterval() but none of them seems working. Here the elephant image is on motion and invisible and visible on click but now I want to pause the motion as well on mouse click.

```
 <html>
        <head>

            <style>

               map{ /*elephant's eye*/
                cursor:default;
                }

                div.b{ /*div of outter box*/
                    width: 850px;
                    height:600px;
                    border: 3px solid blue;
                    float: left;
                }

                div.a { /*div of the elephant box*/
                width: 250px;
                height:250px;
                /*background-color:red;
                border: 1px solid black;*/
                position:fixed;
                cursor:pointer;
                }  

                body { /* body style*/
                cursor:pointer;
                margin: 0px;
                }

                div.c{ /* number box style*/
                width: 150px;
                height:50px;
                border-radius: 5px;
                background-color:red;
                /*border: 1px solid black;*/
                right: 10px;
                float: left;
                color: yellow;
                }

                div.pmenu{ /* pause menu*/
                width: 150px;
                height:50px;
                border-radius: 5px;
                background-color:red;
                /*border: 1px solid black;*/
                margin:0 auto;
                color: yellow;
                }

            </style>

        </head>
        <body>
                <div class='b'  id="clickme">  <!--outter blue box -->
                    <div class='a' id='a'> <!--elephant's box -->
                        <img src="image/download.jpg" alt="elephant" usemap="#elephant" id="img">
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="c"> <!--clicks box-->
                    <p id="para">Clicks: 0</p>
                </div>
                <div class="pmenu"> <!--clicks box-->
                    <p id="par">Clicks: 0</p>
                </div>

            <map name="elephant"> <!--eye mark on the elephant -->
                <area class="yellow" shape="rect" coords="10,10,80,80" href="" />
            </map>

        </body>

        <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
        <script> //Random motion run
            $(document).ready(function(){
                SetOpacity('img', 0);

               animateDiv();
        });
    $(".yellow").on("click", function(e){ //Elephant eye click event
        e.preventDefault();
        SetOpacity('img', 100);
        alert('You won, Play Again?');
        location.reload();
    });

    var button = document.getElementById("clickme") // capture clicks of outter box
    var ps=document.getElementById("para"),
        count = 1;
        button.onmouseup = function() {
            SetOpacity('img', 0);
            if(count<=3){

                ps.innerHTML = "Clicks: " + count;
                count += 1;

            }
            else{
                alert("All tries are over, Try Again?");
                location.reload();
            }
    };

    button.onmousedown = function() {
        SetOpacity('img', 100);


    };
    button.onmousemove= function() {
        SetOpacity('img', 0);

    };

    function SetOpacity( imageid, opacity ) { //Hide the image
        var s= document.getElementById(imageid).style;
        s.opacity = ( opacity / 100 );
        s.MozOpacity = ( opacity / 100 );
        s.KhtmlOpacity = ( opacity / 100 );
        s.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + opacity + ')'; // this is for Internet explorer
    }

    function makeNewPosition(){ //Define random positions by height and width

        // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
        var h = $(".b").height() -280;
        var w = $(".b").width() - 220;

        var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
        var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

        return [nh,nw];    

    }

    function animateDiv(){ // motion
        var newq = makeNewPosition();
        var oldq = $('.a').offset();
        var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);
        $('.a').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function(){
          animateDiv();        
        });

    };

    function calcSpeed(prev, next) { // Speed calculation of the elephant

        var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
        var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

        var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

        var speedModifier = 0.2;

        var speed = Math.ceil(greatest/speedModifier);

        return speed;

    }





        </script>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could think of a few approaches, but essentially you've made an inescapable loop, by having the function call itself; But if you added a condition that stopped the function calling itself, then it would stop and you could start it again by changing the condition that stopped it and calling the function again.

```
function animateDiv(){ // motion
    if(true === doRun) {
        var newq = makeNewPosition();
        var oldq = $('.a').offset();
        var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);
        $('.a').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function(){
           animateDiv();
        });
    }        
};
```

Have "doRun" as a global parameter that you toggle between TRUE and FALSE, when the the elephant is clicked, and when you toggle it to TRUE, also call the "animateDiv" function again.

the above approach should work with the way you've implementede continous movement of the element, but personally, I'd have used setInterval() to keep it running, then add/remove it on clicks.